# Wait HTTP response to resolve function

Tags: express, callback, es6-promise, requestjs

I'm using express.js to create a proxy server to handle calls from a website, manipulate the request, then make a request for a third party provider. I need to wait for the third party response in order response to my website, but can't find a way to make express wait for the response.

My controller file is

```
const model = require('../models/ticketmaster')

const startHour = 'T00:00:00Z'
const endHour = 'T23:59:59Z'

function getData(req, res) {
model({ startDateTime: req.query.startDateTime + startHour, endDateTime: req.query.endDateTime + endHour},res)
res.status(200).send()
}

module.exports = getData;
```

and the model file is

```
const request = require('request');
const config = require ('../config.js');

 module.exports = (req, res) => {

 request.get(`${config.ticketmasterApiUrl}&startDateTime=${req.startDateTime}&endDateTime=${req.endDateTime}`)
 .on('finished', (res) => {
        console.log(res.status)
    })
    .pipe(res)
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you just need to delete the line `res.status(200).send()`?

Comment: By doing this I'm getting the error 'Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400'

Comment: That sounds like a problem with promises but I don't see any promises in your code and `request` doesn't use promises.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
request.get(`${config.ticketmasterApiUrl}&startDateTime=${req.startDateTime}&endDateTime=${req.endDateTime}`)
 .on('finished', (res) => {
        console.log(res.status)
    })
    .pipe(res)
```

To:

```
request.get(`${config.ticketmasterApiUrl}&startDateTime=${req.startDateTime}&endDateTime=${req.endDateTime}`)
       .pipe(res)
```

It only pipes after the request comes back by default, so you don't need `on.('finished'`